# Struts2 Unable to instantiate Action, com.xxx.action.domain.MyAction, defined for '' in namespace '/admin/myresource 'Class must not be null

Tags: configuration, struts2

New to Struts2. I am running this project for the first time and I am getting this error message when browsing to all the resources. It looks like struts.xml is not seen at all.

I have the feeling that it must be something to do with some misconfiguration and/or a missing jar. That "**defined for ''**" (with that empty space between quotes) is the bit that worries me the most.

The project is a web app and is built with maven. Any idea, advice or just thoughts are welcome.

My struts.xml includes my struts-xxx.xml like this

```
<include file="struts-xxx.xml"/>
```

In  struts-xxx.xml:

```
<package name="xxx-admin" namespace="/admin/myresource" extends="my-default">

    <default-action-ref name="default"/>
    <default-class-ref class="com.xxx.action.domain.MyAction"/>

    <global-results>
        <result type="redirectAction">list</result>
        <result name="detail">/WEB-INF/jsp/xxx/detail.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/WEB-INF/jsp/xxx/detail.jsp</result>
    </global-results>

    <action name="default">
        <result type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">list</param>
        </result>
    </action>

    <action name="view" method="view"/>
    <action name="create" method="create"/>
    <action name="update" method="update"/>
    <action name="delete" method="delete"/>

    <action name="commit_create" method="createCommit">
        <result name="detail" type="redirectAction">create</result>
        <!--stay creating-->
    </action>
    <action name="commit_update" method="updateCommit">
        <result name="detail" type="redirectAction">
            <!--stay updating-->
            <param name="parse">true</param>
            <param name="actionName">update</param>
            <param name="id">%{id}</param>
        </result>
    </action>
    <action name="commit_delete" method="deleteCommit"/>


    <action name="search" method="search" class="com.xxx.action.domain.OneMoreAction">
        <result>/WEB-INF/jsp/xxx/search.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="list" method="list" class="com.xxx.action.domain.OneMoreAction">
        <result>/WEB-INF/jsp/xxx/list.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/WEB-INF/jsp/xxx/search.jsp</result>
        <result name="unique_result">/WEB-INF/jsp/xxx/list.jsp</result>
    </action>

</package>
```

Comment: Don't worry, it should be the name of the default action name, but varies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There  was nothing wrong with Struts2 config (or Spring config). The project I was trying to run was coded with Java 1.6 while I was using Java 1.7 ... thanks for your answers and comments

Answer (score 0):

If working with struts and Spring, In Struts.xml, we define actions for particular class and then in the application-context.xml of your project the actual bean of this Action class should be created. Missing bean definition in application-context.xml, struts doesn't find the bean at run time when the Action is called. Hence this error.