# Struts2 cannot instantiate action, Class must not be null after updating to Java 7

Tags: java, eclipse, struts2

I need to update an old project from Java 6 to Java 7. The whole project runs ok on Java 6, but when I change to Java 7, some parts of the project give me this error:

```
Unable to instantiate Action, com.xxx.action.domain.CaseAction,  defined for '' in namespace '/'Class must not be null
```

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493298/struts2-unable-to-instantiate-action-com-xxx-action-domain-myaction-defined-fo), the user said the problem was that the project was coded with Java 6 while he was using Java 7.

But I changed all possible settings to compile the project in Java 7, and run it in Java 7, and there are no build errors. The project runs ok on most part of it, just some specific pages have this problem.

Is there any settings I'm not configuring in the correct way? Or am I missing something?

I'm using Eclipse, and Tomcat 6.

If there's anything you want me to add here, please let me know.

**Update:**

struts.xml

```
     <action name="*_Case" class="com.xxx.action.domain.CaseAction" method="{1}">
        <result name="success">CaseList.jsp</result>
        <result name="inputAdm">CaseForm.jsp</result>
        <result name="inputEduc">CaseForm.jsp</result>
        <result name="cancel" type="redirect">list_Case.html</result>
        <result name="text">text.jsp</result>
        <result name="list" type="redirect">list_Case.html</result>
        <result name="filter">CaseTable.jsp</result>
        <result name="viewlist">CaseViewList.jsp</result>
        <result name="publicViewList">PublicCaseViewList.jsp</result>
        <result name="termos">Termos.jsp</result>
        <result name="delete">CaseList.jsp</result>
        <result name="dicasProjetos">DicasProjetos.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

CaseAction.java

```
public String publicViewList() {
    if(!isNewFiltro()) {
        filter = (Filtro)session.get("FILTRO");

        if(filter != null && !filter.getClazz().equals(getNew().getClass())) {
            filter = null;
        }
    }

    if(filter == null) {
        filter = new Filtro<CaseTO>();
    }
    filter.setActionContext(ActionContext.getContext());
    filter.setClazz(getNew().getClass());
    buildExample();
    ((CaseTO)base).setCaseStatus(CaseTO.CASE_STATUS_APROVADO);
    ((CaseTO)base).setPublicado(Boolean.TRUE);
    filter.setExample((CaseTO)base);
    filter.setPageSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    bases = mgr.getList(filter);
    String basesJson = "";
    ArrayList<CaseTO> list = new ArrayList<CaseTO>();
    try{

        for(CaseTO caseTO: (List<CaseTO>)bases){
            if(caseTO.getLatitude() != null && caseTO.getLongitude() != null){
                if(caseTO.getEducador() != null)
                    caseTO.getEducador().setEducadorInstituicoes(null);
                caseTO.setEducadoresRelacionados(null);
                list.add(caseTO);
            }
        }
        Gson g = new Gson();
        basesJson = g.toJson(list, list.getClass());
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    List<CaseTO> cases1 = bases.size() > 0 ? bases.size() > 2 ? bases.subList(0, 2) : bases.subList(0, bases.size()-1) : new ArrayList<CaseTO>();
    List<CaseTO> cases2 = bases.size() > 2 ? bases.subList(2, bases.size()) : new ArrayList<CaseTO>();

    ActionContext.getContext().put("casesJson", basesJson);
    ActionContext.getContext().put("resultSize", list.size());

    ActionContext.getContext().put("cases1", cases1);
    ActionContext.getContext().put("cases2", cases2);
    return "publicViewList";

}
```

I put the relevant part of the files, as they are a little big.
The URL thats gives me the problem is `/publicViewList_Case.html`, so the method that is supposed to be executed is `publicViewList`, even though apparently it doesn't get executed before the exception is thrown.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Any constructor in `CaseAction`?

Comment: *just some specific pages have this problem.* - Which pages? What is the difference?

Comment: For example when I send a request to this action I posted. And another one. There are no relevant difference between those that work and those that doesn't work. At least in code level. That's why I think is some kind of configuration, because when I run using Java 6 everything is ok.